# TSQL - Replace string before symbol

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace, str-replace

I have a table storing pathes to files on sql server. I need to replace the path before the last backslash:

> C:\Users\APP\AppData\Local\Temp\test\abc deg.pdf

to for example:

> \app\pp\abc deg.pdf

EDIT: The table containts many pathes - I need to run through the whole table and change all pathes.

Comment: replacing C:\Users\APP\AppData\Local\Temp\test\ with \app\pp\. That is what you want ?

Comment: yes - correct. I changed the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@str))
```

to get the index of the first backslash *starting from the end*.

Using `RIGHT` with this index you can extract the string after the last backslash and concatenate it to the new path:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50) = 'C:\Users\APP\AppData\Local\Temp\test\abc deg.pdf'

SELECT  '\app\pp' + RIGHT(@str, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@str)))
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is less circuitious than the answer I gave.

Comment: how can I run through the whole table and change all pathes?

Comment: @r0tt Do an `UPDATE yourTable SET path = '\app\pp' + RIGHT(path, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path)))`

Answer (score 2):

1. Reverse the input string (using [REVERSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms180040.aspx)) and find the index of the first backslash (using [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms186323.aspx)).
2. Take the left part up to that index (using [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms177601.aspx)) and concatenate with the reverse of your replacement string (using `+` operator).
3. Then reverse that to get your final result.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
declare @a varchar(max)='C:\Users\APP\AppData\Local\Temp\test\abc deg.pdf'
select REPLACE(@a,SUBSTRING(@a,1,(LEN(@a)-charindex('\',reverse(@a),1))),'\app\pp')
```

**Update:** For updatingall the table column values.

```
select REPLACE([column-name],SUBSTRING([column-name],1,(LEN([column-name])-charindex('\',reverse([column-name]),1))),'\app\pp')
FROM [Your-table]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be done.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET PATH = REPLACE(PATH, 'C:\Users\APP\AppData\Local\Temp\test', '\app\pp')
WHERE ...
```

This is going to replace `'C:\Users\APP\AppData\Local\Temp\test'` with `'\app\pp'`. Or you can modify the path as required.

**Please test before executing this `UPDATE` statement. I havent specified filters here**